# Using Custom Image View

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use a custom image view but I don't think it's working tho. The image is not displaying. I've surfed the net for answers but the answers are all confusing. :(

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activities.JacintoGate">

<activities.ZoomImageView
    android:name="activities.ZoomImageView"
    android:id="@+id/jgate_view"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="566dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.707"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.542"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_up"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="209dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The activity:

```
public class JacintoGate extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_jacinto_gate);
}

private void display() {

   ZoomImageView imageView = new ZoomImageView(this, getWindow()
           .getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation());

   imageView.setImage(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j_gate),
           this);
}
```

I don't get why it's wrong. I surfed the net for answers but find it all c=so confusing. Hoping for someone to give me some light about it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Where are you calling `display` method?

Comment: That should be inside the onCreate method. I just put it inside a function for easier usage. I used this link as my guide http://androidprogrammingmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/08/zoom-image-on-double-tap-in-android.html

Comment: But are you calling or not `display`? You're code shows nothing about it

Comment: Sorry. In this particular instance, I was not using it.

Comment: That's the problem then :)

Comment: No. :) If I use that method, it creates another ZoomImageView apart from the one in the XML. My problem now is that I made a button to overlay the ZoomImageView in the XML but when I use the **display** method, I can't see or use the button at all. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `display` creates a new instance of `ZoomImageView` but it won't get the one you have on xml. From your replies to my comments, you need to set the image on method `onCreate`

```
ZoomImageView imageView = (ZoomImageView) = findViewById(R.Id.jgate_view);
imageView.setImage(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j_gate), this);
```

Comment: I tried it and it gave me this error


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void activities.ZoomImageView.setImage(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                 at activities.JacintoGate.onCreate(JacintoGate.java:20)

Comment: Are you doing it AFTER `setContentView`?

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. All this time, putting it AFTER was my only error?? I feel so stupid. HAHAHA. Thank you very much @claudio for your patience on answering my questions!! :))

Comment: 1 more question: If I do this  

    _ZoomImageView imageView = new ZoomImageView(this, getWindow()
               .getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation());
       imageView.setImage(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j_gate), this);_

How could I make it that I would be using the same **ZoomImageView** I have in my XML? Which is the **jgate_view**?

Comment: Because of the button that I need to overlay it with. Actually, from the link I gave you a while ago, **ZoomImageView** is a class of its own. I was using it because it has integrated the methods I needed on my project: **Zooming in and out** and **Gestures**. When I do the method you suggested a while ago, I can no longer use the **scroll** method I have in the **ZoomImageView** class :(

Comment: There should be absolutely no difference. I'm sorry but I don't understand your point :(. Maybe you can add a new question with more details